# Why is an explicit comparison needed when using try_lock()?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

I was reading the documentation of [`std::mutex::try_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock) and it had this example on it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>

int main()
{
    std::mutex test;
    if (test.try_lock() == true)
        std::cout << "lock acquired" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lock not acquired" << std::endl;
    test.unlock();  // now unlock the mutex
    test.lock();    // to lock it again
    if (test.try_lock())  // true can be left out
        std::cout << "lock acquired" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lock not acquired" << std::endl;
    test.lock(); // and now the finale (a block)
}
```

In this second if statement he says true can be left out. Why is this so for the second one but not for the first. I checked and it says `try_lock` returns a boolean, so how can it not be either true or false, thus making the `== true` check superfluous?

Comment: The slightly quirky comparison isn't the only issue with that example. More seriously, you mustn't call `unlock()` unless your thread owns the mutex, so the call to `unlock()` should be inside the first `if`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - in general, yes, but in this particular example, no: the call to `try_lock` will always succeed, because nobody else gets a chance to lock the mutex.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Indeed, as an example of how you can get away with abusing a mutex in a contrived situation where you don't need one in the first place, I suppose it's valid. But it looks to me as if it's supposed to be an example of how to use one correctly, at which it fails.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - agreed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x == true` is silly when `x` has type `bool`. `test.try_lock()` returns `bool`, so in **both** cases the test isn't needed.